# merge two multi-dimensional arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How do I merge two multi-dimensional arrays using different keys that have matching values?

i.e. I want the data in arrayOne, 'Member'=> '45', to merge with the data in arrayTwo, 'id' => '45'.

I don't have access to the query, just the result array.

First Array:

```
arrayOne
array (
  558 => 
  array (
    'id' => '558',
    'Member' => '45',    
    'Status' => 'Active',    
  ),
  559 => 
  array (
    'id' => '559',
    'Member' => '46',
    'Status' => 'Active',    
  ),
)
```

Second Array:

```
arrayTwo
array (
  45 => 
  array (
    'id' => '45',    
    'Name' => 'Johnson',
 ),
  46 => 
  array (
    'id' => '46',
    'Name' => 'Smith',
 ),
)
```

Desired Array would be something like this:

```
arrayThree
array (
  45 => 
  array (
    'id' => '45',    
    'Name' => 'Johnson',
    'Member' => '45',
    'Status' => 'Active',  
 ),
  46 => 
  array (
    'id' => '46',
    'Name' => 'Smith',
    'Member' => '46',
    'Status' => 'Active',  
 ),
)
```

This is the code I've most recently tried, which does merge the records, but it doesn't merge them by their matching values. Thank-you for any help!

```
 function my_array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo) {
    $result = arrayThree();
    foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $arrayTwo[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you tagged the language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array1 = array_combine(array_column($array1, 'Member'), $array1);
$result = array_map(function ($item2) use ($array1) {
    $item1 = isset($array1[$item2['id']]) ? $array1[$item2['id']] : null; 

    if ($item2) {
        $item2['Member'] = $item1['Member'];
        $item2['Status'] = $item1['Status'];
    }

    return $item2;
}, $array2);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bed7bf6659b36cdc6b3ce9769ef28e2d1a434f9).